# Howto fix Chrome banding on background images

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, webkit

I'd like to have a radial gradient background. Since I can not achive the desired look using compass I decided to use an SVG image. The output of:

```
background: url(/images/background.svg) no-repeat center center fixed
background-size: cover
```

looked awesome in Safari, Firefox, Safari Mobile and Chrome Mobile but NOT in Chrome. Banding!

So I decided to handle Chrome differently, insert a background image as PNG or JPG after the page is loaded via jQuery. So I created that image:

[image: background image with radial gradient]

I opened the image in Safari, Firefox, Safari Mobile and Chrome Mobile and it looked pretty well, but when I open it in Chrome, it looks incredibly bad.

I am using the most recent Chrome 25.0 on OSX. Can anyone explain, why Chrome is failing so miserably on that [image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7622529/background.jpg)?

Comment: This is unfortunately a long standing bug (2010) in Chrome https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=41756 I'm not sure why the bitmap gradient doesn't work though. Are you sure you the svg gradient is being replaced by the bitmap?

Comment: The gradient is replaced by the image definitely. The gradient looks even worse :) ... I realized that the latest Canary build does not seem to have the SVG problem. The bitmap looks bad as well. Chrome disappoints more and more.